# How can my sister have dark brown eyes, while my parents have blue eyes?

Tags: human-genetics

Both my father and mother have blue eyes, just like me. But my sister has dark brown eyes, contrary to what I've read about the dominance of brown eye genes and recessive blue eye genes. What happened (apart from the possibility that my mother dated a brown eyed guy from which she was born, which for sure didn't happen because we both look like our father and mother; though you never know with those Italians...) that gave her those dark eyes?

Comment: A related 5 year old [post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/728/how-is-eye-color-in-humans-inherited).

Comment: you can visit this page it's fully explained how blue eyed parents can have brown eyed children by just - carrying the gene -http://genetics.thetech.org/how-blue-eyed-parents-can-have-brown-eyed-children

Comment: Another [post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/45303/can-i-figure-out-the-identity-of-my-grandparent-from-this-information/).

Comment: And what would be the answer? I can't infer it from what is written there. Besides the question is about a man with blue eyes and a woman with brown eyes.

Comment: @descheleschilder The answer is that the simple "blue eyes are recessive brown eyes are dominant" explanation is wrong, because that infers that there is a single gene involved in eye color. That is not true.